# To use “that “ after “wrong”

Tags: conjunctions

Can i use that after “wrong” in sentence below. If it is not correct i wonder why it can’t be used like some adjectices such as “sure”.

> 1) Police was wrong that the man in black suit was killer.

Or

> 2) Police was wrong about the fact that the man in black suit was killer .

Comment: Where are your articles? The police, the black suit, the killer. The police were wrong.

Comment: This example shows why the American and English legal systems often use the word "alleged".  The example is not clear about whether the police alleged that that the man was the killer (when in reality he was not), or whether the man was really the killer, but the police did not think he was the killer.

Answer (score 2):

***Wrong that*** is generally only seen when *wrong* is used in the sense of things being morally or ethically wrong, not wrong about matters of fact.

So, let us set aside any other errors in your example. You need to use different words. The police could be ***wrong about*** something, or ***wrong to do*** something, such as "wrong to say that the (etc.)". So you might say:

> The police were wrong **about** the man in the black suit **being** the killer.

Or:

> The police were wrong **about the fact** that the man in the black suit was the killer.

(I don't like that one so much because it's a little unclear, and could be read as asserting that it was a fact that the man in the black suit was the killer - and the police were wrong to say it wasn't.)

Or:

> The police were wrong **to conclude** that the man in the black suit **was** the killer.

There are several other options, variations on these with different verbs or nouns or slight differences in grammar.

Comment: I like your answer. I agree that saying that a person is right that... is more usual than saying that a person is wrong that... We can thus find: *The police were right that the man in the black suit was the killer.* Curiously, this pattern will not work so easily with "wrong".

Comment: @Gustavson: Indeed. Choosing an antonym, or even negating a verb, can sometimes radically change the sort of syntax you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Both can be fixed into **The** police **were** wrong about the fact that the man in the black suit was **the** killer. number two makes more sense, if you want to make the first one clearer you have to make it so the wrong and that are not next to each other, **so no in a normal sentence wrong and that should not be next to each other in this context.**